# Current gen Crossfire compatibility with an old Crossfire board

Tags: compatibility, amd-radeon, crossfire

I've got it in mind to purchase a pair of Radeon HD7770s but the thing is my board is old. CPU-Z tells me that it's a [MSI 770-G45](http://www.msi.com/product/mb/770-G45.html#/?div=Basic) and although its listed as Crossfire-compatible, I'm told that the latest version of Crossfire has been re-engineered to be better and faster, and that implies that I'd need to change boards

Would I be able to use these newer 7770s with an older Crossfire board?

Comment: Who told you this? Because I will be honest the motherboard you have isn't that old. Its was released around 24 months before the card you looking to buy was released. In other words there has not been any major changes to Crossfire since your motherboard was released

Comment: There has not been an update to CrossfireX since 2007.  The current generation of cards (Radeon R9-290) do not even have a port for the bridge because of their design.